# how to specify the maximum number of clusters for the STC algorithm in Solr admin console?

Tags: solr, cluster-analysis

I am using solr 7.7 to do a clustering process. I would like to control the maximum number of clusters created.
Among the list of STC parameters in https://carrot2.github.io/release/4.5.3/doc/stc-parameters/
the parameter to use seems to be maxClusters.

What could be the good syntax to use it in a solr url request ?

I tried to use it in the following url (for example) :

`http://172.18.201.237:8983/solr/SIG2/clustering?clustering.engine=stc&maxClusters=5&defType=edismax&q=*:*&qf=Sig_t&rows=10000&stopwords=false`

But it does not work, I expected at most 5 clusters but I got 8.